# rename (reverse) unix directories with people's last and first name separated by commas

Tags: shell-script, filenames

I have a directory with more than a 1,000 folders on my Mac. Each folder is a person's last name and then first name separated by a comma. For example - Smith, John.

I want to rename all the directories with a shell script so Smith, John becomes John Smith

These directories will be ingested into a DAM system which will take folder names and make all the items under the directory into keywords. The way they are now Smith, John will tag each file under it with both "smith" and "John" as separate keywords. If I can rename all the files to "firstname lastname" without a comma all the files under it can be auto tagged with the person's name as a keyword in the DAM.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `rename` written by Larry Wall, then you can use it. It is the `sed` for filenames. Be careful, some systems have a different tool with the name `rename`.

```
rename -n -e 's/([^,]+), ([^,]+)/$2 $1/' «list_of_files»
```

Replace `«list_of_files»`, e.g. with `*`. Once tested, remove the `-n`.

Answer (score 1):

Perl version of `rename` utility could do it:

```
rename 's/(.+), (.+)/$2 $1/' *
```

*NOTE*: make a backup of the directory tree before running this
 command.  It should work but you didn't give too many details about the names of your directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find .  -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec basename "{}" \; | grep -v '^.$' | awk -F", " '{ print "mv \""$0"\" \"" $2, $1"\""  }' | tee rename.sh
mv "Doe, Jon" "Jon Doe"
mv "Smith, Bob" "Bob Smith"
mv "Roe, Jane" "Jane Roe"
```

You can then `chmod u+x rename.sh` and run it after giving the output from `tee` a once-over.